# Can't accesses setting activity (SharedPreferences)

Tags: android, xml, settings, sharedpreferences

When I run my application there is no menu button to go to the settings activity.
I have a settings activity which uses shared preferences. I call in the Main Activity like this:

```
private SharedPreferences settings;
private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {

        }
    };
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

And this is my settings activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
}
```

And my *settings.xml* is in XML folder and its very simple at the moment. I just want to be able to open settings in my application. The XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General settings" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_username"
        android:title="User name" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_viewimages"
        android:summary="Determines whether lists are shown with thumbnail photo"
        android:title="View images"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I've also added the settings activity to the Manifest file:

```
<activity 
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
```

so far it eclipse doesn't show me any errors. But when I run my application there is no menu to go to the settings page! I was under the impression that when I create a *settings activity*, Android will automatically create a settings menu. But there is no menu button or anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu and sharedpreferences are not directly linked. Shared preferences store values inside storage. Menu would be the graphical layout bringing you to PreferenceActivity that allow you to used shared preferences to store the settings.

You have to first inflate the menu like this in your activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

where menu contains the menu details like these (res/menu/main.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Your setting name"></item>
</menu>
```

This would add "Your setting name" as an option when you click the menu button. Now to make the menu button do something use this (put it in your mainactivity) :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.item1:
        //Do something here like in my case launch intent to my new settings menu
        Intent options1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(options1);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now the menu button called "Your setting name" will launch your settings activity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's created by default. I had to do it myself. Anyway, check the menu file for your activity and check if this menu is used in your activity.

Comment: Do you mean I have to add a settings item in my XML file in the menu folder?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. And then manually handled opening of the preferences activity.